# Rails.cache.fetch not writing new data to cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, caching

I'm having issues when caching some data from an API in rails. I don't know if i have misunderstood low-level caching or if it just isn't possible with my setup.

```
def initialize
# Podio authentication
Rails.cache.fetch("podio_companies_#{Time.now.end_of_year.to_s(:number)}/connection", expires_in: 1.year) do
  Podio.setup(api_key: API_KEY, api_secret: API_SECRET)
  Podio.client.authenticate_with_credentials(CLIENT_EMAIL, CLIENT_PASSWORD)
end

self.podio_companies = Rails.cache.fetch("podio_companies_#{Time.now.end_of_hour.to_s(:number)}/data", expires_in: 1.hour) do
  Podio::Item.find_all(PODIO_APP_ID, limit: 130)[0]
end
```

When the time set in expires_in (1 hour) runs out, the variable is nil and won't refresh.

Comment: Please provide the code correctly. The code provided  is invalid because the initialize method îs not closed .  And would be helpful to see what is Podio.client and what is doing Podio::Item.find_all

Comment: Just missed one "end" after the last block. Podio.client is just an authenticated API client for Podio, an external application (not that relevant), and Podio::Item.find_all just retrieves a big array of information from the app. I'm using 'podio' gem to use Podio.

Comment: Well the  first block of Rails.cache.fetch will just skip entirely the authentication if cache îs already there and If GC runs Podio.client will be Nil . So when the cache for Podio::item expires won't be able to fetch anything. You need to cache separetly the response for Podio.setup.and Podio.client.authenticate. and then use those to call find_all.

Comment: Honestly caching the authentication îs really a bad idea.